# How to edit ContextMenuStrip inside of custom UserControl?

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls

As you know, when you add a ContextMenuStrip to form it will place an icon of it on the bottom of form designer. After clicking that icon visual "menu designer" will appear.

Now assume that I have developed a custom user control which have such (single) ContextMenuStrip inside it. What Iam looking for is a way to show the same "menu designer" for this ContextMenuStrip inside of my custom UserControl after clicking it (my control).

Any ideas how to do that ?! Coz me and google have run out of them ... :/ 
Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

The designer does not support this. I won't say it's impossible but ot will be a lot of work.

Maybe you're better of filling the contextStrip from code (in the hosting Form).

Comment: I was thinking about that, but after implementing such behaviour my userControl would loose point of creating it. The idea was to ease the neccesity of putting 2 pieces of gui and binding them together in favor of one. Thx for post tho! :)

Comment: It's not supported primarily because it doesn't make any sense.  How would you let the control respond to *added* context menu items that it wasn't programmed to work with?